# Split a string into 2 different substrings vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, substring, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to split a string into 2 subs. The first contains the first 236 (0 to 235) chars and the second one from 237 to the end of the string.

```
firststr = str.Substring(0, 235)
secondstr = str.Substring(235, strLength)  'strLength is the total length of the string
```

strLength is generating error : Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
secondstr = str.Substring(235, strLength - 235)
```

Because strLength is the length of the entire string, and you're starting at position 235, you're going past the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd argument is how many charaters you need and not what the end position is. Try something like:
secondstr = str.Substring(235, strLength-235)   (perhaps you also need -1)

Comment: The 2nd argument has in-determinant length, to the end of the string whatever is the length.
I tried -1 didn't work but -235 did.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Normally data the second argument would be the length of the substring you want, in this case `strLength-236`. I don't know vb.net but in C# you do not need to specify the second variable `strLength` for `secondstr` when using substring because the default goes to the end of the string.

[edit] - fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to go to the end of a string then you can leave off the length parameter when using the Substring method. The default is to go to the end of the string.

```
secondstr = str.Substring(236)
```

will get the job done for you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your variable `strLength` has a value that's outside the boundaries of the string `str`.

Answer (score 0):

I note noone picked up the other error in your code as described.

The second argument to `Substring` is the length returned, so `firstStr` contains the same as `Left(str, 235)`, i.e. it contains 235 characters as you've written it, not 236.

For completeness, here's a VB solution to your query:

```
firststr = Left(str, 236)
secondstr = Mid(str, 237)
```